# Angular 2 - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - WebAPI [HttpPost]

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-web-api, http-post, angular2-services

I am trying to call my POST endpoint (ASP.NET WebAPI) from angular 2 http service but the endpoint is not getting hit at all. I have already read several post but none of them worked yet.

From my angular 2 component, I am calling my service like

```
saveCarAuction(): void {
    let respone: ResponseObject;
    this.auctionservice.saveCarAuction(this.auction).subscribe(resp => {
        respone = resp;
    }, error => this.onError(error));
}
```

In auctionservice, I have

```
saveCarAuction(auction: CarAuction): Observable<ResponseObject> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    var api: string = '/CarAuction';
    var url: string = this.baseApiPath + api;
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(auction), options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

In my Web API Controller, I have

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/CarAuction")]
[ActionName("PostCarAuction")]
public IHttpActionResult PostCarAuction([FromBody]CarAuctionViewModel carAuction)
{
    ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject() {ResponseType = ResponseType.Success.ToString()};
    //some action
    return Ok(Utility.SerializeObject(response));
}
```

The final Url of my service call is

```
http://localhost:53796/api/CarAuction
```

The issue is, if I put a breakpoint in my action, it won't be called. I have tried to pass data differently from my service like below:

```
JSON.stringify({ carAuction: auction})
```

I have also tried to call it via attribute routing (although I don't prefer that) but that isn't working either. I have tried to receive a simple json string in my post action and deserialize plus tried updating the return type but it seems that it has decided to play a tricky game.

The response for all the requests (and changes) in my console is below

[image]

I have really ran out of ideas right now to make this simple scenario run successfully.

EDIT 1:
I have included the json I'm passing to my API

```
{
    "carAuction": {
        "carPlateNumber": null,
        "carAuctionId": null,
        "sellerUserId": null,
        "carMakeId": null,
        "carModelId": null,
        "carColorId": null,
        "carType": null,
        "manufacturerYear": 2002,
        "manufacturerMonth": 4,
        "carMileage": 475000,
        "ownershipCount": 3,
        "ownershipType": null,
        "comments": null,
        "notes": null,
        "terms": null,
        "coverPhotoUrl": null,
        "salePublicationDateTime": null,
        "saleEndDateTime": null,
        "auctionType": null,
        "carbidPercentage": null,
        "saleType": null,
        "isHiddenAuction": false,
        "intervalBid": 0,
        "minimumPrice": 0,
        "contactPersonFullName": null,
        "contactPersonCompany": null,
        "contactPersonPhone": null,
        "contactPersonFax": null,
        "contactPersonWebsite": null,
        "contactPersonEmail": null,
        "contactPersonAddress": null,
        "hasAuctionEnded": false,
        "carLocation": null,
        "carMake": null,
        "carModel": null,
        "carColor": null,
        "carAuctionMedia": [],
        "id": "3F8184F7-37F4-4BD9-8B32-FDB8F65D5AB3",
        "appCultureId": null,
        "createdDate": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "isActive": true,
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "modifiedBy": null
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your `auction` value,  you are getting inside `saveCarAuction` function ?

Comment: I have included the json I am passing to API using this format: JSON.stringify({ carAuction: auction }), its the valid JSON

Comment: @AliBaig What's baseApiPath  ?

Comment: Check out my answer in this post : there is a working example that might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337145/how-can-i-get-and-post-an-action-using-angular-2-in-mvc

Answer (score 1):

You should check the response from the server using the [network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#view_details_for_a_single_resource) and append it to your question.
Looks like your JSON-Response is corrupt. This often happens when an error message is printed before the output is sent or when nothing is sent.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be is that you redirect all your requests to `index.html` or that you are receiving a custom `404` page. Try going to http://localhost:53796/api/CarAuction in your browser and check the response.

> Unexpected token < in JSON

This almost always refer to a html page trying to be parsed to `JSON`. The response image you post, is not the response you get from the server. You should check the network tab for that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ASP.NET Web API returns response which does not have JSON format.

For example, your Web API returns string value like this:

```
bar
```

But you need to return the response in the following format:

```
{foo: 'bar'}
```

So your response should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/CarAuction")]
[ActionName("PostCarAuction")]
public IHttpActionResult PostCarAuction([FromBody]CarAuctionViewModel carAuction)
{
    ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject(){ResponseType = 
        ResponseType.Success.ToString()};
    return Ok(new {foo = response});
}
```

In the above method, we are returning [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), however, we can return [DTO object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5):

```
return Ok(new PersonDto() { Name = response });
```