# Angular using Http request doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core

I'm trying to populate data from my DB using Angular and some API services.

My code:

```
        $http.get("/api/trips")
            .then(function (response) {
                angular.copy(response.data, vm.trips);
            }, function (error) {
                vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load data: " + error
            });
```

And my API `GET()` :

```
        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
                var results = _repository.GetTripsByUsername(this.User.Identity.Name);
                return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TripViewModel>>(results));
         }
```

No data is showing. I'm pretty sure the errors is popping because the `this.User.Identity.Name` is passed wrongly, but I'm confused.

If I change the method from `GetTripsByUsername` to `GetAllTrips` , which select all the trips without filter, then the data is shown properly in the page.

The function it self works, if I use it via PostMan, it recognize my cookie and bringing me the correct trips(inside postMan) but on the page it doesn't work ..

Comment: Do you have any specific error message showing with the `GetTripsByUsername` method ? What is the error code returned in the network tab ?

Comment: I don't see any errors on console, and `GetTripsByUsername` working through Postman @AlexBeugnet , I just enter the path and it returns the correct trips.

Comment: No, I meant through your application, and not Postman. You said `I'm pretty sure the errors is popping...`. I believe it's from your angular application, and therefore what is the error message contained with "Failed to load data:" and the error code returned by your browser ?

Comment: That's the thing. It doesn't say "failed to load data"  , and I can't find any error messages.. If I change the path to tripss then it does. That's why I think it "works" properly, but the `Identity.name` is not being recognized or something . @AlexBeugnet

Comment: Check this old post out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337145/how-can-i-get-and-post-an-action-using-angular-2-in-mvc/41341743#41341743

I believe this is what you are looking to do

Comment: @AlexBeugnet It doesn't matter what I'm trying to do.. I'm following an online course, so I'm not suppose to change anything. This is what he did, step by step, and it doesn't work for me.. so I try understanding why .

Comment: I'd need more information on your project then... Could you provide a simple github repo or something ? 
Given the example, I believe you are calling the controller correctly, but nowhere in your angular code you call the your `get()` method (you are using the HTTP get() from angular, but you need to specify which method from your controller you want to call, which is also badly named `get()`.

Comment: Or there is something I don't get correctly, and the issue is somewhere else but I can't know about it if I can't see the issue...

Comment: The situation is like so: If I replace the method inside the `get()` function, to another method `getAllTrips` , which basically selects * trips, then the page present the data correctly. That means the function is getting called, and imply that the problem is with the `GetTripByUsername` method. Now, if I run the get() function with `GetTripByUsername` via Postman, it returns the correct filtered trips from my DB, which means it identify the user identity cookie i have. So why does it work through postman and not through the angular running that service? @AlexBeugnet , hope I'm clear.

Comment: Yes this is very clear. Then I guess your insight about `this.User.Identity.Name` is right, but I have no idea how you can make it work unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't because your angular application is not authenticated and `this.User.Identity.Name` is null.
You need to send credential in your angular code like that:

```
$http.get("/api/trips", { withCredentials: true })
            .then(function (response) {
                angular.copy(response.data, vm.trips);
            }, function (error) {
                vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load data: " + error
            });
```

But it depends on your authentication mecanism, This code will not work for Oauth or Basic authentication. If you use Oauth, you must send the Authorization header containing the authorization token.

Comment: I use cookie authentication , and adding this didn't work.. still same problem. But it sounds right, that was my suspicion that the identity being sent it wrong . Any other idea?

Comment: find a way to post authenticate your application using cooky then

Comment: Not sure I understood you :S