# Windows Authentication and Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I am writing an Angular 4 application that needs to get some data from Asp.Net WebApi. We are using windows authentication for the WebAPI and I am wondering how I can pass user's windows identity from my Angular Application to WebApi. I've found couple examples that are involving nesting your application with MVC application but I would to keep UI away from MVC. Is there a way to do it without adding .net mvc to my Angular website?

Comment: Maybe that link will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337145/how-can-i-get-and-post-an-action-using-angular-2-in-mvc/41341743#41341743

Comment: From what I can see is that they are using regular authentication. I would like to use Windows Authentication

Comment: @AlexanderM was this question answered properly?  If so please mark answer.

Answer (score 5):

When you send your http request from Angular to your WebAPI you need to use
RequestOptions({ withCredentials=true})

Here's a sample security service that calls an api

```
@Injectable()
export class SecurityService {
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:64706/api/security/';
private auth: Auth;
private options = new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true });

constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Creating Service');

    console.log('Service Pre Http');

    this.http.get(this.baseUrl, this.options)
      .map((res) => this.extractData<Auth>(res))     
      .subscribe(newItem => {
        console.log('Service Subscribe');
        this.auth = newItem;
      })

  }

  public isUser(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    if (!this.auth) {
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, this.options)
        .map(res => {
          this.auth = this.extractData<Auth>(res);
          return this.auth.isUser;
        });
    }
    else {
      return this.auth.isUser;
    }


  }

  private extractData<T>(res: Response) {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
      throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }
    const body = res.json ? res.json() : null;
    return <T>(body || {});
  }

}
```

This is the auth class

```
export class Auth {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  isUser: boolean;
}
```

If you are using .net Core then in your WebAPI Controller you can now access
`this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

**NB:** If you are using ASP.Net Core 2.0 then you need to follow the "Windows Authentication (HTTP.sys / IISIntegration)" section here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

You must also remember to enable Windows Authentication on the host e.g IIS or IISExpress.

You will likely need to enable CORS the documentation here is good:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

If you get errors around "preflight checks" then you will also need to enable Anonymous Access

Comment: you said in your response "IIS or IISExpress". Have you tried IISExpress and it worked? Because I have and I can not make it work

Comment: Yes,both work using Chrome. What browsers have tried?

Comment: Only Internet Explorer. That is the main browser that needs to be supported. I will try Chrome to see if it works

Comment: Just FYI to use RequestOptions you need to `import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';`.