# Angular 7 Windows Authentication Login Popup is not showing

Tags: angular, windows-authentication, angular7

I'm trying to use windows authentication in my angular 7 application. My problem is that the popup for the windows integrated authentication is not showing up and I get the following error when I make a request to the API.

The windows integrated authentication is working if I make a direct request to the backend using restlet client or just a direct request with Google Chrome.

[image]

My code in the frontend looks as follows:

win-auth.interceptor.ts

[image]

AppModule.ts

[image]

Console output: 
[image]

Similar To the following question but the solution does not work for me:

[Windows Authentication and Angular 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163240/windows-authentication-and-angular-4-application)

I have also tried out the following tutorial:

https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2017/08/04/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-in-an-angular-4-3-1-application-with-a-stand-alone-web-api/

Edit:

Error Specification:
[image]

Backend Cors configuration:

[image]

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, the error is about the `OPTIONS` method. It's a pre-flight request before the actual request is made. You need to ensure that `OPTIONS` request method is allowed on your server side.

If you are using WebAPI and IIS, it has a built-in handler for `OPTIONS` requests. Make sure you are not removing this handler in your web.config like following.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Since you are setting `withCredentials: true` option, it works in conjunction with [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) header. Angular's `HttpClient` makes [`OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) request to check which request methods are allowed. And in your case `OPTIONS` method is not allowed.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have edited my post now. The Options Method was already allowed.